# Detecting extent of randomness of a binary time series

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, randomness

I have several time series that take a value of 1 if an event occurs and 0 otherwise. I would like to measure randomness of each time series is. What would be a good measure for this? The reason I am trying to do this is to gauge the predictability of event occurrence.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "how random" and also say why you want to do this?

Comment: @mdewey: Thanks for your question -- i've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Please [merge your accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist).